# Change all text color inside brackets within a string in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to change color inside a string where text between brackets.

Example:

> (Flutter) development using (dart).

So how to change color of text inside brackets? it will solved by using Richtext.

Problem is that when I have a long string with multiple brackets, how to change color every single string that between brackets programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expression and find text between brackets and then use this library to highlight searched words https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_highlight#-installing-tab-

Answer (score 1):

You can use a RichText Widget

```
RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
            text: 'Now how to change color of  ',
            style: TextStyle(color:Colors.black),
            children: <TextSpan>[
              TextSpan(
                  text: 'new ', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: Colors.red)),
              TextSpan(text: 'and! '),  TextSpan(
                  text: 'Flutter!', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: Colors.green)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

#### Result

[image: Example]

#### References

1. [DartPad Example](https://dartpad.dev/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b)
2. [RichText class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html)